# How to use Update Panel for ASP.Net and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have a textbox with onkeyup event that call JavaScript function GetEmployee() this function gets items from database where full name contains value typed on textbox.

Everything is working, but I want to add a button save with server-side functionality which is doing an error on post back .

I want to use asp:updatepanel as solution for the error but don't know how to do it .

Here is my code

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtSelectUser" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" class="InputFormStyle form-control" OnKeyUp="GetEmployee();"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstEmployee" runat="server" onchange="SelectUser();"></asp:ListBox>
       <asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="btnadd_Click" ID="btnadd"/>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedUserId = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].style.display = "none";

        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].onchange()
        {
            SelectUser();
        }
    });
    function SelectUser() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].options.length; i++) {
            if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].options[i].selected) {
               
                $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_txtSelectUser")[0].value = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].options[i].text;
                selectedUserId = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].options[i].value;
                $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].style.display = "none";
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    function GetEmployee() {
        selectedUserId = 0;
        var FN = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_txtSelectUser")[0].value;
        if (FN == "") {
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: '..../GetDataByFn',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    fullname: $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_txtSelectUser")[0].value
                }),

                type: 'post',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].options.length = 0;
                    if (data.d.length != 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                            var opt = document.createElement("option");
                            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].options.add(opt);
                            opt.text = data.d[i].FullNameEN;
                            opt.value = data.d[i].Id;
                            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].options.add(opt);
                        }
                        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].style.display = "inline-block";
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeControl_lstEmployee")[0].style.display = "none";
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                }

            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application. Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: I don't see where in the code that some button triggers a post-back. However, do keep in mind that a update panel ALSO does a post-back, or what is better called a "partial" post-back. Your round trip and even page.load event STILL does trigger when you use a UD panel. So, using a UD panel may not solve your issue. I might have missed with my quick glance at  your code - but I don't see where the post-back is currently occurring. A UD panel still does a post-back, but only that part of the page is posted when you do this - hence UD panel does not eliminate a post-back, but makes a partial one.

Comment: Ah, I see the button save now.

Comment: Remove `OnClick="btnadd_Click"` or turn event validation off.

Comment: @Lain  I can't remove OnClick event since this button must save item in database, I want to do it in c# (asp.net)

Comment: The event should usually not be defined manually in the markup if it is an event from the CodeBehind. There you should have an event like `btnadd.Click` which gets transformed into something like `javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("btnadd", "", true, "", "", false, false))` in the markup. If `btnadd_Click` is a client event, you should use `OnClientClick` instead of `OnClick`.